# IE 7 links colour CSS problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, hyperlink

I am working on [this](http://www.movend.com) site and encountered the following problem when i opened on IE 7.

**Case** I am seeing default windows colours for the links. (Blue for unvisited and purple for unvisited links) because the "Use windows Colours has been enabled". I have looked at the 
LoVe HAte concept too. I am not using them. 

I also tried to "Disable Changing IE’s Link Color Settings" in gpedit.msc
Still no solution

**Problem** I want to use my own colours for the webpages (white) which has been set in my CSS. It works fine on all other browsers. Help me to override these colours (blue and purple) with my own colour (white).

I want to fix this problem using my CSS or anything related to code

The link colour will not change anytime. It will always be white. Please help me out.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you should accept the answers to your previous questions first.

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks for poiting it out. I have accepted a few answers now. Thanks once again

Comment: your page isn't loading for me, maybe you can post the html + css?

Comment: The website is up now. Please go to www.movend.com and see the colour of the links and help me with this regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's  simple. IE doesn't understand **inherit** property.
And we have two variants

1.
IE hack to maintain **inherit**

```
color: inherit; 
//color: expression(this.parentNode.currentStyle['color']);
```

2.
to change

```
a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:inherit;
}

a:hover {
 cursor:pointer;

}
```

to

```
a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff; // any color
}

a:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#fff; // any color
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I got it... You are awesome!